# FPDF Coloured Page Edge

Tags: fpdf

I am using FPDF to generate a pdf document which works fine, but i am trying to add some colour to brighten it up a little and so i am trying to find away, if it is possible to add a coloured border along the left hand side of the page, which runs from top to bottom and is about 1cm wide.

I am using the following, but even though i have set the margins to 0, the cell still starts about 1cm in from the edge of the page, is this the correct way to achieve this?

```
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->SetMargins(0, 0, 0);
$pdf->Cell(10,250,1,true);
$pdf->SetFillColor(976,245,458);
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `SetMargins()` before `AddPage()` ?

Comment: Thank you, i can't believe it was that simple

Comment: I will write this as an answer, so that others can easily find it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put `SetMargins()` before `AddPage()`: When calling `AddPage()`, the current margins are copied (not referenced) into the page.